# How to check Spark step status programmatically (submitted on EMR cluster)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-lambda, amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

I created a simple step function as follows : 
Start -> Start EMR cluster & submit job -> End

I want to find out a mechanism to identify whether my spark step completed successfully or not?

I am able to start EMR cluster and attach a spark job to it, which successfully completes and terminates the cluster.
Followed steps in this link : 
[Creating AWS EMR cluster with spark step using lambda function fails with "Local file does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549234/creating-aws-emr-cluster-with-spark-step-using-lambda-function-fails-with-local)

Now, I am looking to get the status, th ejob poller will get me information whether the EMR cluster created successfully or not. 
I am looking at ways how I can find out Spark job status

```py
from botocore.vendored import requests 
import boto3
import json 
def lambda_handler(event, context): 
    conn = boto3.client("emr") 
    cluster_id = conn.run_job_flow(   
        Name='xyz',   
        ServiceRole='xyz',   
        JobFlowRole='asd',   
        VisibleToAllUsers=True,   
        LogUri='<location>',   
        ReleaseLabel='emr-5.16.0',   
        Instances={     
            'Ec2SubnetId': 'xyz',     
            'InstanceGroups': [         
                {           
                'Name': 'Master',           
                'Market': 'ON_DEMAND',           
                'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',           
                'InstanceType': 'm4.xlarge',           
                'InstanceCount': 1,         
                }
            ],   
            'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': False,   
            'TerminationProtected': False,  
        },  
        Applications=[
            {    
            'Name': 'Spark'
            },
            {
            'Name': 'Hadoop' 
            }
        ],  
            Steps=[{     'Name': "mystep",     
            'ActionOnFailure': 'TERMINATE_CLUSTER',     
            'HadoopJarStep': {       
                'Jar': 'jar',       
                'Args' : [
                        <insert args> , jar, mainclass
                    ]     
                }   

            }] 

    )
    return cluster_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cli or sdk to [list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/list-steps.html) all steps for the cluster and then [describe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/describe-step.html) particular step to get its status.